# Making Capybara work with sprockets-commonjs gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

I'm trying to test react components that are in es6 modules using Capybara. We use the sprockets-commonjs gem to require the modules and it works fine on the development environment. However, running the Capybara tests against it seems to fail due to the request function. It doesn't seem I can include the commonjs in the spec_helper. I wonder if anyone made this work.

Comment: What driver are you using?

Comment: I tried Poltergeist, selenium, and webkit, all seem to yield the same issue.

Comment: Poltergeist doesn't support es6 - so that's not going to work (unless you're transpiling).  Another thing to check for is JS errors which can prevent JS from functioning properly when some of the files are concatenated by sprockets (in the test and productiion environments), but work fine in the development env because they aren't concatenated.  Other than that you're going to need to show some code with your setup.

Comment: What would you say is the safest javascript_engine to try? I got a javascript error on the request("Router") part. It does work in production (we use heroku review apps and they work as production), so it's something with the capybara/javascript_engine configuration I assume. 
I will try selenium on chrome again...

Comment: mmm, and now it works with Selenium +chrome. I made a lot of changes when I was last using the webkit one, I'll try to understand which of the changes made it work...

Comment: Both poltergeist and capybara-webKit use Qt and have limitations in their support of newer JS features. So if you're using ES6 features and not transpiling to ES5 before deploying ,because you don't have to support older browsers, then your only real choice is selenium. With chrome would be the best bet since the newest FF is missing some features when paired with gecko driver and selenium-web driver 3

Comment: Well, we do transpile using babel, and we don't support much older browsers (unfortunately we do support IE 11 and Edge :( ). But I think it was the combination of some changes I made and using the selenium chrome driver again. The issue seem to stem especially from the way the commonjs-sprockets gem works, I'll probably go over it next week and detail the exact things that made it work...